# Graphics card not behaving as expected on new PC build

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, gpu

I have recently built a new PC:

- Ryzen 9 5900x
- Evga 3070 Ultra
- Corsair Vengeance 32 gb
- EVGA Supernova 850 GA

And I have been having some interesting issues. Intermittently, the screens will go black for 3 seconds and then come back on.

Whenever a game begins to get demanding it crashes the game. I receive driver compatibility errors from Valorant, and it only returns a livekernelerror 141 from the reliability manager.

To try to resolve this I started with a memory test to a depth of 8 and found no errors. I then clean booted windows. I then started to use benchmarks and found that Heaven Benchmark crashes 12 seconds in, I also did a firestrike benchmark, also closed after 12 s, while running HWinfo64 to collect that data and I will link all the data below.

I am not really sure; my plan today is to replace the two power cables running to the gpu. Other than that, I have reached the end of my technical knowledge. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is [log output on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PLwg9kGH).

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: How many watts is your PSU?

Comment: My PSU is 850 watts

Comment: Bugcheck 0x141 means the graphics driver crashed and Windows could not reset it in a timely manner. Is your graphics driver up to date?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the to the most recent drivers. When that didnt work I clean booted and rolled it back.

Comment: I edited to try to add a better image of a 3d mark run but didnt do as well as my previous editor.

Comment: @data_is_fun You forgot to include the pastebin link

Comment: Thank you @Gantendo, also after more tests I believe it is just a bad graphics card. That wasn't my first assumption as it was an out of the box graphics card, but I feel as though i have exhausted all other possibilities.

Comment: My last 2 AMD cards have died after a driver update, have you tried rolling back? Just as another basic check, you are plugged into the graphics card right and not the mobo's video output?

Comment: I just realised, I totally misread what GPU you said you had. ignore my first question, but my second still stands.

Comment: Yes, I tried rolling it back and I am coming directly out of the graphics card withe display port. @Burgi

Comment: "Whenever a game begins to get demanding it crashes the game." You should check the event viewer for details about the crash.